# Startup Sign in screen MacBook Pro - Strange option box says Home - Switch with options of Keyboard, Pointer, or Location. What is this?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, geolocation, macos

[image]When I restart my MacBook I get the sign in screen or the Startup Sign in screen and lately a small window I guess it would be Called is sitting on top with its own x to close out but it is a  Strange option box that has a black back ground with white writing and it says Home - Switch  with 3 options under that have a icon and one says Keyboard, middle one says Pointer, and last one says  Location. What is this?

Comment: It might be good to add a picture of the screen to your question.

Comment: I added a picture. : )

Comment: I have from time to time investigated the Accessibility options. Im not sure if I did this.

Answer (score 1):

You have somehow enabled [Switch Control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202865), a macOS Accessibility feature.

Follow the instructions on the page above and figure out how to disable it, or configure it to something that may be useful for you.